# Linker fails with NBIS library

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am trying to use the NBIS library on OS X, but I am getting a problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "distance(int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-2db11c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I tried using the `.a` archive, as well as the `.o` files in there - no luck - same problem.

The source code I am trying to compile (test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lfs.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << distance(1, 2, 3, 4) << endl;
}
```

Here are the execution lines that I tried (unsuccessfully):

```
$> g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb -g -Wall test.cpp -o test.bin -lm -lc++ 
$> g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb -g -Wall test.cpp -o test.bin -lm -lc++ -L/NBIS/Main/lib -lmindtct 
$> g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb -g -Wall test.cpp -o test.bin -lm -lc++ -L/NBIS/Main/lib -l:libmindtct.a 
$> g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb -g -Wall test.cpp /NBIS/Main/lib/libmindtct.a -o test.bin -lm -lc++ 
$> g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb -g -Wall test.cpp /NBIS/Main/lib/util.o -o test.bin -lm -lc++
```

Just to confirm that the libraries actually have the method declared, I checked what is inside the `libmindtct.a` archive:

```
$> ar t libmindtct.a
__.SYMDEF SORTED
<MANY FILES .o>
util.o
<SOME MORE .o FILES>

$> ar -x libmindtct.a util.o
$> nm util.o
                 U ___stderrp
00000000000008d0 T _angle2line
                 U _atan2
0000000000000a10 T _closest_dir_dist
0000000000000600 T _distance
00000000000008a0 T _find_incr_position_dbl
                 U _fmod
                 U _free
                 U _fwrite
0000000000000650 T _in_int_list
0000000000000920 T _line2direction
                 U _malloc
0000000000000000 T _maxv
0000000000000360 T _minmaxs
00000000000001b0 T _minv
0000000000000690 T _remove_from_int_list
0000000000000630 T _squared_distance
```

To compile the library I use the following:

```
$> cd ~/Downloads/NBIS/
$> ./setup.sh /NBIS/Main --64
$> make config && make it && make install LIBNBIS=no && make catalog
```

Comment: Link order matters, try `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.bin -lname` suppose your library name is `libname.a` And , if  I am not mistaken, in OSX your program is by default linked to the math library. So `-lm` is redundant. And I don't understand what you try to accomplish by `lc++`

Comment: Please, read the question. This doesn't even come close to a solution. Also, http://libcxx.llvm.org/

Comment: btw, I wasn't proposing a solution, I was just saying a the way you compiled it is wrong. Generally you put the linker options after the `-o ouput` option in the order in which the libraries need to be linked. For example `gcc -lm in.c -o in.out`  is different from `gcc in.c -o in.out -lm` where the former would fail in my linux if i'm using a function from the math library.Forgive me with my comment on `lc++`,  i didn't get what you were trying to accomplish :) Good luck

Comment: About the order you are right, I forgot that my `g++` is a custom script that rearranges all the `-l` flags to avoid backward dependencies - I will edit the question.

Comment: I feel the bash tag is unnecessary   here

Answer (score 0):

`lfs.h` from NBIS is C only. You need to enable C linkage for `lfs.h`:

```
extern "C" {
        #include <lfs.h>
}
```

Additionally, you should not need to manually link `libc++` or `libm` using `g++`.